# MySQL - Pulling List Pending on Dates

Tags: mysql, sql, unique

**I have a table like this:**

```
ID_____PostingDate_____PosterID
--------------------------------
1______05/01/2012______450
2______06/30/2012______451
3______02/17/2013______451
4______12/10/2012______451
5______06/14/2012______452
6______06/15/2012______452
7______05/01/2012______453
8______06/04/2012______453
9______04/05/2013______454
10_____05/05/2013______454
```

I'm trying to get a list of all PosterIDs that have posted in May or June of 2012 and have not posted again since then.

**Desired Result from the table above:**

```
PosterID
--------
450
452
453
```

**I've tried:**

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(PostingDate, '%m-%Y') IN ('05-2012', '06-2012')
```

and

```
SELECT UNIQUE(a.PosterID)
FROM 
    (SELECT ID, PostingDate, PosterID FROM table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(PostingDate, '%m-%Y') IN ('05-2012', '06-2012') 
    ) a
WHERE DATEDIFF(PostingDate, NOW()) > 365
```

though neither of these are getting close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PosterID
FROM table1
WHERE PostingDate BETWEEN '2012-05-01' AND '2012-06-30'
AND posterID NOT IN (SELECT PosterID
  FROM table1
  WHERE PostingDate > '2012-07-01');
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/900494/8)</kbd>

Comment: @Ken. That's not accurate. The first query tells you what are the records that happened in that 2 month period. the not in will remove from the results the ones that have posted after '2012-07-01'. You can check in sqlfiddle. if you remove the AND posterid NOT IN .. part it will return 451 also.

Comment: Ah - You're right...I had unknowingly manipulated your posted formula. Following what you've posted worked! +1 coming soon after I finagle a little more. Thank you for your post & follow-up

Comment: Thanks again. I have posted a "2nd half" to this question/more elaborate part of this formula if you're able to help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077332/mysql-pulling-list-depending-on-date-and-category

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT PosterID
    FROM (  SELECT PosterID, MAX(PostingDate) AS latest_post
              FROM tbl
          GROUP BY 1) latest_posts
   WHERE latest_post BETWEEN '2012-05-01' AND '2012-06-30'
ORDER BY PosterID;
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
where PostingDate < '2012-7-1' and PostingDate >= '2012-5-1'
```